# Can the cost factor be changed of Windows' credential cache?

Tags: passwords, windows, caching

I'm having a hard time finding relevant documentation from Microsoft (or any third party, for that matter) about any registry key that may change the cost factor of cached credentials.

One can control how many logons are stored through the registry key `CachedLogonsCount`, but what I would like to change is the cost parameter of PBKDF2. The default is a cost of 10240, which is quite low (we managed to crack an 11 character password (of a domain admin) by using a large wordlist and hashcat on an ~$8/hour VPS with a GPU for about one hour).

Of course, turning off the cache (and especially not logging in with a domain admin account on attacker-accessible workstations) is the proper solution for this kind of attack. However, our client does not want to turn off caching for availability reasons: if the network goes down, individual systems should still work. Since they refuse to turn it off altogether, and since rolling out disk encryption and physical access controls will take a while, it would be good to be able to recommend changing a simple setting in the meantime.